# Does Intellij IDEA support @RooJpaRepository?

Tags: spring, intellij-idea, spring-roo, spring-data

IntelliJ 12.1.6 Ultimate, with following plugins enabled :

- AspectJ Support
- AspectJ Weaver
- Spring Support
- Spring Data
- Spring AOP and @AspectJ

I have a Spring Roo project, which use Spring Data repository API. Following are snippet codes :

## Repository class

```java
package my.package;

@RooJpaRepository(domainType = Thing.class) 
public interface ThingRepository {
}
```

## Roo generated aspect file

```java
privileged aspect ThingRepository_Roo_Jpa_Repository {
    declare parents: ThingRepository extends JpaRepository<Thing, Long>;

    declare parents: ThingRepository extends JpaSpecificationExecutor<Thing>;

    declare @type: ThingRepository: @Repository;
}
```

## Spring JPA config

```xml
<repositories base-package="my.package" />
```

---

But in xml file, IntelliJ told me

[image: No matching beans found]

So whenever I use method like find/save in IntelliJ, it will be marked as "Cannot resolve method"

[image]

However, both IntelliJ and Maven compiles without any problem, just the method not resolvable in editor. What could be the problem?

Comment: The problem is the Classpath and AspectJ, I'm mot sure how to do it in IntelliJ, but in Eclipse you must enable the project as AspectJ project and rebuild the project. Hope it helps.

Comment: I have added an issue on intellij issue tracker. http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-120006. Let's see what happens

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Bad news, I think you must wait for that functionality. See this:

http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-59138

In short: **Nowadays Intellij doesn't support AspectJ declare parents nor declare precedence**

Intellij developers have been  playing around with this feature since Intellij 11 (See the comments about [No technical block, just lack of resources](http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-59138#comment=27-473369))

The issue is marked to be resolved on Intellij 14. How long is that? See that Intellij 13.1 is planned to be released on [Q2 of 2014](http://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/IDEADEV/IDEA+13.1+EAP), so it will take a while.

Comment: To be clear, does this issue also mean that the line `declare @type: ThingRepository: @Repository;` isn't recognized? I'm trying to get IntelliJ's JPA tooling working in a project where entities use `@RooJpaActiveRecord`, and I'm wondering if this same issue is the problem.